# Android Boot Completed Receiver doesn't work on system app

Tags: android, boot

My application contains a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver like described in other threads here. It works perfectly until I changed my app into a system application. Now the Receiver does not trigger the event anymore.
Any ideas for this issue? I'm using Android Kitkat 4.4.2 on a Radxa Rock Pro. Compiled my own image to register the app as system application.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you add the `@android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permissions?

Comment: @Trinimon As I described above the BOOT_COMPLETED triggering worked fine until I changed my app into a system application. When I switch it back to a "normal" app it works again. The necessary permissions are set of course.

Answer (score 0):

we need more detail to help you, post the code and the manifest, also debug log, in other hand you must use `Log.i(TAG, "onReceive.");` to know if the problem is in `onReceive()` or when trying to run the `service class`.